# Excel VBA: Dynamic x-axis of diagram depending on input

Tags: excel, vba, diagram

Task: User inputs two dates, these make the intervall. A diagram has to show only the intervall of time. Values for the y-axis are calculated via a table on a sheet not used by the user. My idea is to use the date input to let vba hide columns selectively

The table is hardcoded basically and gets populated with numbers depending on the intervall the user chooses.
X1 of the intervall is the startdate. Now the bold piece of code is an attempt to use r1c1 notation to use the enddate as input for the respective column where the macro starts to hide numbers not needed for the intervall. The error I get is "runtime error 13 - types incompatible".

Where is my issue? I declared the date as long, the watch function shows me that enddate2 is calculated correctly. But somewho I think my synatx is wrong

```
Sub LWA_Erzeugen()


    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim endDateNumber As Long
    Dim endDateNumber2 As Long
    
    ' Prompt the user to enter the start dat
    startDate = InputBox("Start-Datum eingeben (mm.dd.yyyy):")
    Range("I2").Value = startDate


    ' Prompt the user to enter the end date
    endDate = InputBox("End-Datum eingeben (mm.dd.yyyy):")
    Range("J2").Value = endDate
    

    ' Check if the entered values are valid dates
    If IsDate(startDate) And IsDate(endDate) Then
    
    Unhide_Contiguous_Columns
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B2 PV Production").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'unhide all columns
    
        endDateNumber = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B1 PV Application").Range("K2").Value)  ' why 3: start to count after column b
        endDateNumber2 = endDateNumber + 3
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B2 PV Production").FormulaR1C1.Columns("R1C& endDateNumber2 & :R1C320").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hidden columns are not shown in diagrams
              
       
    End If


End Sub
Sub Unhide_Contiguous_Columns()

    Worksheets("B2 PV Production").Range("B:HT").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `FormulaR1C1` is a property of a range which sets or returns a formula. It does not have a `Columns` property.

Comment: I tried it without "FormulaR1C1" but then I have a type mismatch error. It seems I'm declaring something wrong or the type has to be changed somewhere but I couldn't get it working

Comment: You are trying to hide some columns from `endDateNumber2` to 320?

Comment: If I correctly understand/deduced what you try doing, please try using`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B2 PV Production").columns(endDateNumber2).resize(, 320).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`. It will haide starting from `endDateNumber2` column (inclusive), as many columns you need hiding (320 columns)...

Comment: FYI Here's a little information on [how to use row-column (R1C1) notation](https://wellsr.com/vba/2022/excel/vba-formular1c1/).